# R - boxplotting specific variables against one another

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, boxplot

I am using the dative data frame within R, and I am trying to plot only the LengthOfRecipient == 'nonpronomial' against Modality. I gathered all the LengthOfRecipient == 'nonpronomial':

```
library('languageR')
lor.np = dative[dative$PronomOfRec == 'nonpronominal',]$LengthOfRecipient
```

I have tried nesting this subset function, and applied vectors, but I cannot figure out a way to then access the Modality column for only the items in `lor.np` and store it in `mod.np`, so that I can plot and analyze the data with:

```
boxplot(lor.np, mod.np)
```

I'm very new to R and the syntax is extremely confusing. Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: which data set are you using? is `dative` from a package or your personal data? does `boxplot(LengthOfRecipient ~ Modality, droplevels(dative[dative$PronomOfRec == 'nonpronomial', ]))` work

Comment: It is from the LanguageR package. This seems to be working, so thank you! Does droplevels() remove everything except for the given argument (so in this case, it removes everything except where PronomOfRec == 'nonpronomial'?

Comment: You don't really need `droplevels`. when you create a subset data frame, all of the factor levels will still be there even if there are no observations for that level. So when you use a function like `boxplot`, it will create a space for the unused level but not plot anything. I just assumed you may have some unused levels after subsetting

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to select all the columns you want at once and then use the `formula` feature in `boxplot` rather than using vectors:

```
library('languageR')   
lor.np <- dative[dative$PronomOfRec == 'nonpronominal',
                 c('LengthOfRecipient','Modality')]

head(lor.np)
#    LengthOfRecipient Modality
# 2                  2  written
# 3                  1  written
# 5                  2  written
# 6                  2  written
# 7                  2  written
# 11                 2  written

## but you don't even need to select the columns:
lor.np <- dative[dative$PronomOfRec == 'nonpronominal', ]

boxplot(LengthOfRecipient ~ Modality, lor.np)
```

[image]

After looking at the data, you don't need `droplevels`, but here is an example when it may be useful:

```
dat1 <- dative[dative$Modality == 'written', ]
boxplot(LengthOfRecipient ~ Modality, dat1)
```

[image]